# C++: references for container elements

Tags: c++, casting, overloading

I try to write a container-polynomial with *operator[]* returning *references* and *const references*. But when I want to use *const operator[]* inside of reference, C++ chooses *operator[]* without *const*. Should I implement *const operator[]* as private function and use it in both places or is there a way to make compiler use const-returning function?

```
template <typename T>
class Polynomial {
    std::vector<T> data;

    void DeleteTopZeroes () {
        int degree = Degree ();
        while (degree && !data[degree]) {
            --degree;
        }
        data.resize (degree + 1);
    }

public:
    Polynomial (T constantTerm) {
        data.resize (1);
        data[0] = constantTerm;
    }
    int Degree () const {
        return data.size () - 1 ? data.size () - 1: data[0] ? 0 : -1;
    }

    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef const T& const_reference;

    const_reference operator[] (size_type degree) const {
        return degree <= Degree () ? data[degree] : 0;
    }

    class reference {
        Polynomial<T>& _polynomial;
        int _degree;

    public:
        reference (Polynomial<T>& polynomial, size_type degree)
            : _polynomial (polynomial)
            , _degree (degree)
        {}
        reference operator= (const T& rhs) {
            if (_degree <= _polynomial.Degree ()) {
                _polynomial.data[_degree] = rhs;
                _polynomial.DeleteTopZeroes ();
            } else if (rhs) {
                _polynomial.data.resize (_degree + 1, 0);
                _polynomial.data[_degree] = rhs;
            }
        }
        operator const T&() const {
            return _polynomial[_degree];
            // compiler uses "reference operator[] (size_type degree)" and stucks on recursion
            // but there is "const_reference operator[] (size_type degree) const"
            // which seems to be more similar, isn't it
        }
    };

    reference operator[] (size_type degree) {
        return reference (*this, degree);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `return static_cast<const Polynomial&>(_polynomial)[_degree];` to force compiler to select const version.

Ok which cast to use is proving controversial, so here is an approach without any cast needed.

```
    operator const T&() const {
        const Polynomial& temp = _polynomial;
        return temp[_degree];
    }
```

Comment: To add constness `const_cast` is preferred.

Comment: Why? const_cast lets me make some dangerous casts. I think static_cast is safer.

Comment: `const_cast` is used to add or remove constness. This is what you are doing here, so you would use it. I don't see the "danger".

Comment: `static_cast` is also used to add constness. There is no danger in this case, but the risk is making a bad cast by accident.

Comment: Because `const_cast` does not allow you to change the _type_.

Comment: No but it lets you modify a const object. That's worse in my opinion.

Comment: casting constness off from object and trying to modify it(Trying to modify const variables) invokes UB, so you shouldn't care either way, because at that point it is your fault not language's

Comment: @Creris No but I want to minimize chance of something bad happening, even if it's my fault.